# Perform a substring replacement in a single line in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm reading in MAC addresses on my LAN using the `arp -a` command and parsing the output. On OS X, some MAC addresses are returned with hex values lacking leading zeros. I've figured out how to insert the leading zeros using regex:

```
>>> mac = '8:AA:C:3:ED:E'
>>> mac = re.sub('^(?P<hex>.)(?=\:)','0\g<hex>',mac)
>>> mac = re.sub('(?<=\:)(?P<hex>.)(?=\:)','0\g<hex>',mac)
>>> mac = re.sub('(?<=\:)(?P<hex>.)$','0\g<hex>',mac)
>>> print mac

08:AA:0C:03:ED:0E
```

This works, but I'm sure there's a way to perform a replacement in a single line for an arbitrary MAC address, where any hex value can potentially lack a leading zero...I just can't figure it out.

Comment: As much fun as trying to do this in one line is, we're mostly throwing readability to the wind...

Comment: True. Though, some of these answers have definitely improved readability compared to my initial solution that relied on cryptic regex syntax.

Comment: BTW, as much as it may just be shouting at the ocean, there's something else to note in alecxe's answer: IEEE has been trying to get people to use dashes instead of colons for the separators in MAC addresses, in order to prevent confusion with IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> mac = '8:AA:C:3:ED:E'
>>> print ':'.join([i.zfill(2) for i in mac.split(':')])
08:AA:0C:03:ED:0E
```

To use it like a "standard library" with a "convenient interface":

```
>>> def fix_mac_adr(adr):
        return ':'.join([i.zfill(2) for i in adr.split(':')])
>>> fix_mac_adr('8:AA:C:3:ED:E')
'08:AA:0C:03:ED:0E'
```

One-liner (from Mike DeSimone):

```
>>> fix_mac_adr = lambda adr: ':'.join([i.zfill(2) for i in adr.split(':')])
```

Comment: @alecxe Yes, you're right. More efficient as a generator.

Comment: Make the definition one line, too! `fix_mac_adr = lambda adr: ':'.join(str(i).zfill(2) for i in adr.split(':'))`

Comment: If someone told you that `str.join`ing a generator expression is "more efficient" than joining a list comprehension, [they're wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python/9061024#9061024)

Comment: Correcting myself: `str(i)` is redundant since the result of `str.split` is a list of strings. Therefore `fix_mac_adr = lambda a: ':'.join([i.zfill(2) for i in a.split(':')])`

Answer (score 8):

One option is not to reinvent the wheel and use [`netaddr`](http://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/) module:

```
>>> from netaddr import EUI
>>> mac = '8:AA:C:3:ED:E'
>>> mac = EUI(mac)
>>> mac
EUI('08-AA-0C-03-ED-0E')
>>> str(mac)
'08-AA-0C-03-ED-0E'
```

As a bonus, you would get a nice [standardized API](http://pythonhosted.org//netaddr/api.html#mac-addresses-and-the-ieee-eui-standard).

Comment: Is there a standard library solution with a similarly convenient interface?

Comment: @user2357112 mm, not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @user2357112 What's wrong with a third party library?

Comment: @SethMMorton: [Dependency hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell), for one thing.

Comment: @user2357112 If this is the only thing you want to do with the mac address, just create a function.

Comment: Maybe back in 2001, but since this package is on PyPI, it can be automatically installed if you use pip.  I have been using python for years now, and have *never* experienced dependency hell when installing a python library because I use pip.

Comment: Guys, it's a never-ending argument. My boss would kill me for this approach, but I would do it anyway :) Some people just have a special thing with dependencies :)

Comment: @alecxe: Where I work, the special thing is called "contractual requirements", namely "software must run on a stock RHEL 6 (or whatever) box with no additional packages installed, and no you're not allowed to install your own as part of the delivery, and no virtualenv either." I.e. no fun.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using string formatting as follows:

```
mac = '8:AA:C:3:ED:E'

>>> print ':'.join('{:0>2}'.format(i) for i in mac.split(':'))
08:AA:0C:03:ED:0E
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mac = '8:AA:C:3:ED:E'
":".join(("0" if len(part)==1 else "")+part for part in mac.split(":"))
```

Output:

```
Out[45]: '08:AA:0C:03:ED:0E'
```

Comment: The [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) string method may be helpful here.